# Python parsing a text file and logical methods

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

I'm a bit stuck with python logic.
I'd like some some advice on how to tackle a problem I'm having with python and the methods to parsing data.

I've spent a bit of time reading the python reference documents and going through this site and I understand there are several ways to do what I'm trying to achieve and this is the path I've gone down.
I'm re-formating some text files with data generated from some satellite hardware to be uploaded into a MySQL database.

This is the raw data

```
TP N: 1   
Frequency: 12288.635 Mhz   
Symbol rate: 3000 KS  
Polarization: Vertical  
Spectrum: Inverted  
Standard/Modulation: DVB-S2/QPSK  
FEC: 1/2  
RollOff: 0.20  
Pilot: on  
Coding mode: ACM/VCM  
Short frame  
Transport stream
Single input stream  
RF-Level: -49 dBm  
Signal/Noise: 6.3 dB  
Carrier width: 3.600 Mhz  
BitRate: 2.967 Mbit/s
```

The above section is repeated for each transponder `TP N` on the satellite
I'm using this script to extract the data I need

```
strings = ("Frequency", "Symbol", "Polar", "Mod", "FEC", "RF", "Signal", "Carrier", "BitRate")  
sat_raw = open('/BLScan/reports/1520.txt', 'r') 
sat_out = open('1520out.txt', 'w') 
for line in sat_raw: 
    if any(s in line for s in strings): 
        for word in line.split(): 
            if ':' in word:
                sat_out.write(line.split(':')[-1])
sat_raw.close()
sat_out.close()
```

The output data is then formatted like this before its sent to the database

```
12288.635 Mhz
 3000 KS
 Vertical
 DVB-S2/QPSK
 1/2
 -49 dBm
 6.3 dB  
 3.600 Mhz
 2.967 Mbit/s
```

This script is working fine but for some features I want to implement on MySQL I need to edit this further.

1. Remove the decimal point and 3 numbers after it and MHz on the first "frequency" line.
2. Remove all the trailing measurement references `KS`,`dBm`,`dB`, `Mhz`, `Mbit`.
3. Join the 9 fields into a comma delimited string so each transponders (approx 30 per file ) are on their own line

I'm unsure weather to continue down this path adding onto this existing script (which I'm stuck at the point where the output file is written). Or rethink my approach to the  way I'm processing the raw file.

Comment: Fix your formatting using the Code button.

Comment: You should be able to replace `any(s in line for s in strings)` with `any(line.startswith(s) for s in strings)`.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance in formatting the question. I will make sure future posts are correctly presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is crude, might not work in corner cases, but it is a good start.

```
import re
import csv

strings = ("Frequency", "Symbol", "Polar", "Mod", "FEC", "RF", "Signal", "Carrier", "BitRate")  
sat_raw = open('/BLScan/reports/1520.txt', 'r') 
sat_out = open('1520out.txt', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(sat_out)
csv_output = []
for line in sat_raw:
    if any(s in line for s in strings): 
        try:
            m = re.match(r'^.*:\s+(\S+)', line)
            value = m.groups()[0]
            # Attempt to convert to int, thus removing the decimal part
            value = int(float(value))
        except ValueError:
            pass # Ignore conversion
        except AttributeError:
            pass # Ignore case when m is None (no match)
        csv_output.append(value)
    elif line.startswith('TP N'):
        # Before we start a new set of values, write out the old set
        if csv_output:
            csv_writer.writerow(csv_output)
            csv_output=[]

# If we reach the end of the file, don't miss the last set of values
if csv_output:
    csv_writer.writerow(csv_output)

sat_raw.close()
sat_out.close()
```

#### Discussion

- The csv package helps with CSV output
- The re (regular expression) module helps parsing the line and extract the value from the line.
- In the line that reads, `value = int(...)`, We attempt to turn the string value into an integer, thus removing the dot and following digits.
- When the code encounters a line that starts with 'TP N', which signals a new set of values. We write out the old set of value to the CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for setting that out with comments, that generates the format i was looking for. I noticed the integer conversion was global over all the values. To isolate that to only convert the  "frequency" value which is the first field in each row would i need to map the columns so i had a reference for the first column and insert an exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

strings = ("Frequency", "Symbol", "Polar", "Mod", "FEC", "RF", "Signal", "Carrier", "BitRate")  

files=['/BLScan/reports/1520.txt']
sat_out = open('1520out.txt', 'w') 
combineOutput=[]
for myfile in files:
    sat_raw = open(myfile, 'r') 
    singleOutput=[]
    for line in sat_raw: 
        if any(s in line for s in strings):
            marker=line.split(':')[1]
            try:
                data=str(int(math.floor(float(marker.split()[0]))))
            except:
                data=marker.split()[0]
            singleOutput.append(data)
    combineOutput.append(",".join(singleOutput))    

for rec in combineOutput:
    sat_out.write("%s\n"%rec)
sat_raw.close()
sat_out.close()
```

Add all the files that you want to parse in `files` list. It will write the output of each file as a separate line and each field comma separated.